# If any item in a list is contained

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script that iterates through a list of files in a directory. Based on words inside the filenames, it would categorize them into three groups. To complicate things, there are now exceptions to this. The exceptions are in a list. My problem is that I can't get it to check for "any" of the items in the list, and if not there, continue to categorize. The excepted word can be anywhere in the filename. I can get it to find things in the list and do something using a for loop, but it'll then move to the next iteration and ignore the previous excepted word and categorize it incorrectly.

This is how I want it to work, but the any( doesn't work like this apparently.

```
exceptions = ["one", "two", "three"]
for i in filenames:
   if any(exceptions) in i:
      do this
   else:
      do this
```

Comment: Read also [mcve]

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
exceptions = ["one", "two", "three"]
for i in filenames:
   if any(e in i for e in exceptions):
      do this
   else:
      do this
```

Comment: I did need to change this to the following... but otherwise it was perfect. Thank you.
for i in filenames:
   if any(e not in i for e in exceptions):
      do this
   else:
      do this

Answer (score 2):

**Here is solution:**

```
filenames = ['foo', 'bar']
 
exceptions = ['one', 'two', 'three']

check =  any(item in exceptions for item in filenames)
 
if check is True:
    print("The list {} contains some elements of the list {}".format(filenames, exceptions))    
else :
    print("No, filenames doesn't have any elements of the exceptions.")
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use 3 separate if/elif statements if your number of exceptions/conditions is minimal and you want to handle each exception differently:

```
for i in filenames:
   if "one" in i:
      categorize_as_one
   elif "two" in i:
      categorize_as_two
   elif "three" in i:
      categorize_as_three
   else:
      pass
```

However, if your list of exceptions is quite long and you only want to capture if any exception is present and group those filenames together, @zipa's answer is way cleaner.

Comment: So, what you outlined is how I have it setup... This particular problem would happen inside the third elif statement. I could then make another block inside with if and elifs to accomplish this goal, but I was hoping to be able to keep the excepted words in a list, or some other easily updated list type object. If this is the only answer, so be it, I'll have to make the extra code blocks for each excepted word.

Comment: @Andrew does zipa's answer accomplish what you're trying to do?